# Spring Boot Sendmail

Tags: linux, spring, spring-boot, smtp, sendmail

I can't configure Spring and Sendmail to work together.

Spring side:

pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.host=localhost
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
```

send mail code(works fine with gmail)

```
@Async
@Override
public void sendActivationEmail(String username, String activationToken) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(username);
    message.setSubject(EmailUtils.EMAIL_ACTIVATION_SUBJECT);
    message.setText(String.format(EmailUtils.EMAIL_ACTIVATION_BODY, activationToken));
    this.javaMailSender.send(message);
}
```

Linux side:

/etc/mail/access

```
Connect:localhost.localdomain           RELAY
Connect:localhost                       RELAY
Connect:127.0.0.1                       RELAY
```

/etc/mail/local-host-names

```
mydomain.com
```

/etc/mail/virtusertable

```
noreply@mydomain.com noreply
```

(I have added noreply as a user)

I don't get any errors. Nothing in logs. No sent email as well. How do I configure it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain timeout values are infinite in Spring Boot by default.
Try to set the timeout values to reasonable values as suggested [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html) and see if it is timing out.

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connecttimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html

Also set the from address:

message.setFrom(...);

Comment: It worked out but after I switched back to gmail. 10x